# parse data from csv and visualize it in graph javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I'm trying to parse csv file, this is my code

```
var directors ={};
var csv = d3.csv("movie.csv",function (data){

for (var i =0; i<data.length;i++){
    var dir= {};
    dir["director_name"] = data[i]["director_name"];
    dir["budget"] = data[i]["director_name"];
    dir["budget"] = +data[i]["budget"];
    dir["gross"] = +data[i]["gross"];
    dir["average"] = (dir.gross+dir.budget)/2;
    directors.push(dir);
}
```

});
    console.log(directors);

when i'm printing it i'm getting all the object,but when i'm trying to print the array length i'm getting array.length=0 get specific index in.
i need to visualize some data in the  chart

```
//Chart
var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 1200, 1200);
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, d);
chart.setBounds(60, 30, 800, 800);
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "budget");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "gross");
chart.addMeasureAxis("z", "average");
chart.addSeries(dimple.plot.bubble);
chart.addLegend(200, 10, 360, 20, "right");
//chart.setStoryboard("year");

chart.draw();
```

Comment: `directors = []` ? instead of object, use array

Comment: i need a couple of data fields, how do i do it

Comment: what do you mean? not sure i understand the question. you said array.length is 0, but i don't see you use any arrays...

Comment: use @Shaniqwa's suggestion.  Then you will have an array of objects.  Each object in the array will have the data fields you need.

Comment: i changed directors to array

Comment: and it didn't work

Answer (score -2):

```
var directors =[];
var csv = d3.csv("movie.csv",function (data){

    for (var i =0; i<data.length;i++){
        var dir= [];
        dir.name = data[i]["director_name"];
        dir.budget = +data[i]["budget"];
        dir.gross = +data[i]["gross"];
        dir.average = (dir.gross+dir.budget)/2;
        directors.push(dir);
    }

});
console.log(directors[0]);
```